# SourceTree - rebase --interactive - Merge conflict aborts rebase

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution

How can I use SourceTree for doing an interactive rebase on another branch, if the rebase causes merge conflicts?

What I observe:
I use SourceTree to do an interactive rebase, by

- right clicking on the branch I want to rebase upon, and
- selecting "rebase children ...interactively".
- SourceTree offers me the "Interactive rebase from " dialog, which allows me to squash commits, etc.
- No matter what I instruct SourceTree to do there, if I tell SourceTree to continue by clicking OK,
- SourceTree recognizes a merge conflict, like this:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c sequence.editor='C:\Users\DNTRAINING\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.3.5\tools\stree_gri' -c core.editor='C:\Users\DNTRAINING\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.3.5\tools\stree_gri' rebase -i --autosquash 1b9102ed53ec63bd6d38a9436663bf58bda590b1
>   Auto-merging f3.txt
>   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in f3.txt
>   Rebasing (1/3)
>   error: could not apply af56da4... feature_rebase_test02 first attempt
>   Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
>   "git add/rm ", then run "git rebase --continue".
>   You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
>   To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
>   Could not apply af56da4... feature_rebase_test02 first attempt
>   Completed with errors, see above.

- but does not allow me to fix the conflict,
- but instead simply aborts the gibt rebase command and I am back at where I was in the beginning.

So, how do I do a rebase --interactive with SourceTree, if I also have merge conflicts to solve?
Thanks, Klaus

Comment: I’d say use the terminal, as the rebase hasn’t been aborted.

Answer (score 11):

**Solution**

1. **Do not** click the `Close` button on the message dialog box.
   **Close SourceTree** by right-clicking on the taskbar button and clicking close.
2. Re-open SourceTree, resolve the conflicts and commit.  (The commit message will have to be entered manually - another bug.)
3. Click `Actions` > `Continue Rebase`.

(Repeat 1 - 3 for additional conflicts)

**Cause**

> This behaviour is attributable to this open SourceTree bug:
>
> https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2493
>
> (has two duplicate bugs ending in 2715, 2912)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution really works. It's very bad that this issue still not fixed.